# How can I bind values from Apex to my options variable in LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have a custom datatable which accepts options like below:

```
import getTimezones from "@salesforce/apex/IntroductionSelector.getTimezones";
...
        {
            label: "Timezone",
            fieldName: "timezone",
            sortable: false,
            type: "picklist",
            typeAttributes: {
                placeholder: "Choose timezone",
                options: [
                    { label: "Greenwich Mean Time", value: "GMT" },
                    { label: "Pacific Standard Time", value: "PST" },
                    { label: "Eastern Standard Time", value: "EST" }
                ],
            }
        },
```

Using my getTimezones method how can I bind the `label` as `MasterLabel` and  `value` as `DeveloperName`?

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getTimezones()
{
    return JSON.serialize([SELECT MasterLabel, DeveloperName, Offset__c FROM Timezone__mdt]);

}
```

Comment: In my opinion, you can Deserialise the json on LWC side and store Timezone__mdt in an array. Then loop on this array to populate options from your dataTable. As you just need to retrive your record apex side, it should be better to use a wire (including that you don't have to use json format  with wire)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to JSON.serialize your data from Apex.  If your Apex method looks like this...

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Timezone__mdt> getTimezones() {
    return [SELECT MasterLabel, DeveloperName, Offset__c FROM Timezone__mdt];
}
```

...it will show up in JavaScript looking like this...

```js
[
    { 
        MasterLabel: 'Greenwich Mean Time',
        DeveloperName: 'GMT',
        Offset__c: 0
    },
    { 
        MasterLabel: 'Pacific Standard Time',
        DeveloperName: 'PST',
        Offset__c: -8
    },
    // etc.
]
```

Given this type of data, maybe the simplest way to populate your columns is with an [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, like this:

```js
get columns() {
    return [
        { 
            label: 'Name', 
            fieldName: 'name' 
        },
        {
            label: 'Timezone',
            fieldName: 'timezone',
            sortable: false,
            type: 'picklist',
            typeAttributes: {
                placeholder: 'Choose timezone',
                options: this.timezones.map(tz => {
                    return {
                        label: tz.MasterLabel,
                        value: tz.DeveloperName
                    }
                }),
            }
        }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a small wrapper class and return a list of those as well.  Iterate through your list of Timezones and create create a new instance of the wrapper class for each Timezone.

```
public class PicklistOptions {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String label { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I did try this and return the list of picklist options but this hasnt worked